# Serve a PHP website with PHP files being remote

Tags: php, proxy, reverse-proxy

This is the situation:

I have a LAMP server, which serves HTML, PHP, etc... Now I have remote folder, somewhere in the web, which has a directory full of PHP files, images, an MVC folder structure (CodeIgniter), etc...

Now, What I want to do is that instead of every time I want to serve those PHP files, instead of downloading them and uploaded them into my LAMP server, I want to use those PHP files directly and serve them in my LAMP server.

Again, I want the PHP files from a folder in another server, which I only have access to the direct link to each individual file, being serve in my LAMP server, so if I access my website, for instance: www.website.com/page1, gets the folder structure from the remote web server or all PHP files, and get serve within my server.

I know this sounds a little bit complicated but I'm not sure what to use... Maybe reverse proxy? Do you think I may download the files directly and constantly syncing the files? If anyone gets with a good solution I may even pay that person...

***EDIT(1)***
Good answers so far... but I think I did not make a good question so here it goes again:

I have access to a "list" of PHP files, and in order to get them I need to authenticate myself using oath via PHP. Once I get authenticated, I can retrieve a list of PHP, html, etc.. files, each one of them having a public URL that anyone can access. So the think is that instead of downloading all files in that repository, and serve those files, I want to be able to reuse that repository's web space and I just serve these files myself. So basically I want to be able to have symbolic links to urls, which I think is not possible, but being able to just read the files and serve the PHP logic, even though the files are elsewhere.

I'm concern about the security issues involved, but if someone could help me I will be thankful... Also if you are interested in what I'm doing I always can use a partner for this project which I intent to use it in charity, but still can pay that person.

Comment: how are the 2 servers connected ? is there a HTTP server running on the second server ? heard of [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a smart thing to do.  You open yourself up to potential security issues, but at a minimum, you will significantly slow your site down.

I would recommend that you simply script synchronizing the files on both servers over SSH by a script.

**Edit:** ManseUK's suggestion if [rsync](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html) is also a good one.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Do you have the ability to mount the remote folder as an [NFS](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/) volume, or perhaps with [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html)?  If those options are available, either could work for you.  You'd mount the remote folder locally and tell your local web server to serve files from that path.</strike>

Not that it would be the most efficient setup in the world, but I don't know why you have all this split apart in the first place.  ;)

You could write a cronjob to grab the remote file list every X minutes/hours/days then store the results locally, then write a simple script to parse those results upon request.  Alternatively, you could still use an NFS or SSHFS mount to read the remote paths in real time and build whatever URL's you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ftp access to the remote server, you could mount the folder using fuse, and serve as usual for apache.